# wget is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: screenshot]

I'm having trouble downloading a dataframe using Jupyter Notebooks from the NBA API. I downloaded WGET as you see in the screenshot I provided , but i keep getting an error message saying 'wget is not recognize as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you sure installing the `wget` Python package also installs _a terminal command_ called `wget`? `!wget <stuff>` will attempt to run `wget` in the terminal (_not_ in Python).

Comment: Indeed, you seem to be confused (understandably so) about the difference between the command line utility wget and the python bindings to control it. You can download the windows version of wget [here](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html#download). You need both.

Comment: to use `!wget` (with `!`) you need program `wget`, not python's module `wget`

Comment: Let me try. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up Python's library and the underlying linux command. Try this code in a Python cell:

```
import wget
url = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
myfile = wget.download(url)
```

The requests is also a good Python library for downloading webpages and files.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
doc = requests.get(url)
with open('razorback.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(doc.content)
```

Comment: I did what you told me Matt.

Comment: It works fine with the URL you used above. But when I use this URL 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/PY0101EN/Chapter%205/Labs/Golden_State.pkl' I get this message.  HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. It's funny because is the same ecxact url that copied from the Skill Network Labs. It works just fine over there

Comment: If I make a call  using the url above from the Command Prompt it works as well. It seems like the url above it's not working only in the Jupyter Noteebook.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had the same issue with wget function not working. The alternative I found was copying the http link which downloads the csv file to your computer. then you can use the panda.read_csv function to load the data in jupyter from your file location. But make sure if your file location uses \ instead / either change them or put an r before hand shown in the 'Screen Grab'. A bit of a run around but it works when you can't use the skill Network Lab

[Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TT0I.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://www.dsfsfdfggf'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'file_name_for_save.extension')
```